# Отслеживание состояния формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть форма с инпутами, селектами, и проч form-элементами. Так же есть простые кнопки в виде `<a class="button">`, которые могут добавить или изменить какие-то данные не только в селектах, а просто дорисовать текст в какую-любо ячейку таблицы что находится внутри формы. Ах да, кстати сама форма - это `<div class="myForm">`, но это не важно. Чтобы отследить что-либо, нужно вешать обработчики событий на всевозможные элементы которые могут изменить ее состояние, или сверять *html* контент формы, но мне не кажется что это хорошо.

Подскажите способ, как это лучше всего сделать? Или может есть либа которая решает такую задачу?

UPDATE:
По observer, почему-то таким образом обработчик не срабатывает:

```js
 wnd.find("input").on("DOMAttrModified", function (e) {
                    if (e.originalEvent.attrName === "value") {
                        console.log("##DOMAttrModified, value changed");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Использовать Angularjs например

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), возможно он вам поможет.

Статья про него:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/202366/

Пример из статьи:

```
// выбираем элемент
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// создаем экземпляр наблюдателя
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });    
});

// настраиваем наблюдатель
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

// передаем элемент и настройки в наблюдатель
observer.observe(target, config);

// позже можно остановить наблюдение
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: Пробовал заюзать это: https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe но почему-то не работает модификация атрибутов, т.е. если появился атрибут - то срабатывает обработчик, а если изменился существующий - то нет. Например вот таким образом, не видит изменений "value": wnd.observe({subtree:true, childlist:true,characterData: true, attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['value','class','selected','checked'] }, function(record) {
                        App.log(record)
                    });

Comment: Как раз таки эта либа использует  MutationObserver